# Слайдер на jquery с ползунком и стрелочками

Tags: jquery, javascript

Подскажите ссылку на сайт библиотеки, с помощью которой можно реализовать слайдер как на сайте
http://www.sony.ru/
Второй слайдер сверху, с ползунком и стрелочками одновременно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я почему-то считаю что jQuery UI будет намного лучше в данном случае. Пакет Wijmo если смотреть глубже.

- [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/)
- [WIJMO](http://wijmo.com/)

---

Answer (score 0):

См. официальный [сайт плагинов jQuery](http://plugins.jquery.com/search/node/scroller%20type%3Aproject_project) .